# Keep a div on screen

Tags: jquery, css

This is my setup, I have two divs side by side with a `float: left` the one on the left contains a list of anchor links for the text in the right div. So you click the title in the left div and the screen jumps to the respective content in the right div.

The right div contains a large amount of text and the menu is pretty small so I would like the menu to stay on screen at all times.

I got this to work using jquery but there are two problems;

- It is VERY jumpy, i would like it to be smooth.
- It gives the menu a fixed position which then causes the right div to move behind the menu.

I tried to fix the second problem by making the right div absolute and giving it a `left` value but that then caused the content to burst out the bottom of the containing div rather than the containing div expanding to fit the content.

I hope all of that makes sence, thank you

**JQuery**

```
$(window).scroll( function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > $('.servicesLeft').offset().top)
        $('.servicesLeft').addClass('floating');
    else
        $('.servicesLeft').removeClass('floating');
});
```

**CSS**

```
.floating {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
}
```

**EDIT**

JSFiddle Link - http://jsfiddle.net/Rx93t/

Comment: Something like this http://jsfiddle.net/HcW3H/?

Comment: @ChrisMoutray do some jsfiddle to visualize what you are trying to do pls

Comment: @okok I'm not sure I follow?

Comment: @ChrisMoutray Nearly, the menu div starts of in the middle and i want it to move to the top and then stick there

Comment: @ChrisBull when you say middle, do you mean vertically or horizontally centered to the screen?

Comment: Either way you don't need js for this css positioning should do the trick

Comment: the div is under the main menu and header and then when the page starts to scroll i want the div to scroll to the top and stick there, thanks

Comment: Chris provide a jsfiddle example. You'll receive a better support if some of us work right on the issue. Developers time is expensive no body have time to question you and to build scenarios. If the problem is specific provide example a simple rule.

Comment: thanks - edited to include jsfiddle link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to store the initial top position of the element into a variable then test if the window has passed it, otherwise you are testing against its new position everytime which causes flickering.

So,

```
var y = $('.servicesLeft').offset().top;

$(window).scroll( function() {
if ($(window).scrollTop() > y)
    $('.servicesLeft').addClass('floating');
else
    $('.servicesLeft').removeClass('floating');
});
```

and to fix the problem of the div going in front of the other you need to use `position: relative` and `z-index`

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Rx93t/3/

Answer (score 0):

See the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/anpsmn/B2Je7/7/)

- I have used jQuery [scrollTo](http://flesler.blogspot.in/) plugin for smooth scrolling when you
  click on a link.
- Then I have a code where in I keep a check on window scroll event
  and apply class nav-fixed when scrolled down.

Hope this is what you wanted.

#### On click scroll

```
   $('#list li a').on('click', function () {
      $.scrollTo($(this).attr('href'), 750);
   })
```

#### Window scroll event

```
    $(window).scroll(function () {

      if (!$('.nav').attr('data-top')) {
        // If already fixed, then do nothing
        if ($('.nav').hasClass('nav-fixed')) {
            return;
        }
        var offset = $('.nav').position();
        $('.nav').attr('data-top', offset.top);
      }

      if ($('.nav').outerHeight() -$('.nav').attr('data-top')  <= $(this).scrollTop())   
      {
        $('.nav').addClass('nav-fixed');
      } 
      else 
      {
        $('.nav').removeClass('nav-fixed');
      }

    });
```

Comment: Thanks - the main issue i'm having though is that the content moves behind the menu in my example - http://jsfiddle.net/Rx93t/ - you need to view it on a large screen to the two divs are side by side